# How to pass Callback in c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

When i call a async function from third party library then i found that the function need to pass the callback.

the function is

```
Library.getResult(object options, Action<library.libresult<dataCollection>>  callback
```

can someone tell me how i can pass callback to this function in silverlight.

thanks

Comment: Your post is entirely unclear, unhelped by the invalid signature and the lack of context. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a delegate for method that accepts the result. You can for example use a lambda expression to create that:

```
Library.getResult(options, result => {
  // code here runs when the result arrives
});
```

You can also declare a named method:

```
private void HandleResult(library.libresult<dataCollection> result) {
  //...
}
```

Then just use its name in the call, which will automatically create a delegate for it:

```
Library.getResult(options, HandleResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

An `Action<library.libresult<dataCollection>>` is a method that takes a `library.libresult<dataCollection>`, so the following should work:

```
Library.getResult(options, result => {
     // do something with result
});
```

Here, `result` will be the `library.libresult<dataCollection>` it gives you back. Presumably (but not  for certain) this is async, so you may need to consider the threading issues etc.